# Groom entrance song - what are some key genres, artists, and songs to help select in the Mizrachi/Sefardi area?

Tags: wedding, music, ethiopian-beta-israel

I'm getting married soon, bezrat HaShem. But I need suggestions for a song to play when I approach the chuppa. I'm British Sefardi (daati), she's Israeli Ethiopian (Beta Yisrael), I'd like something Mizrachi/Sefardi.

Any ideas?
What are some examples -- songs, artists,or genres -- that could help inform a selection in this style? General genres or particular artists or songs might help others with a similar question.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Mazal tov! Unfortunately, this platform [isn't well-suited](/help/dont-ask) to opinion questions where every answer is equally valid. I'm going to close this question to answerers therefore. I do recommend, though, that you check out [our chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64803915#64803915), a more chatty place, where people may have suggestions for you.

Comment: Oma Khartoum ...Rembetiko.. Giorgios Ntallaras .. hip-hop

Comment: https://jewish-music.huji.ac.il/content/liturgy-beta-israel-music-ethiopian-jewish-prayer